# PowerBi Report Builder (Paginated Report) to "ALL" inside Single Selection Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, powerbi

How to include "Select All" or "All" inside a Single Selection Parameter in Paginated Report (PowerBi Report Builder). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation and shift response. I am just wondering how to do the same with the powerbi builder optimized for DAX, Not SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add the option to the dataset query that supplied the parameter values, typically you UNION the extra value in. For example, if you had a list of Categories from a `Categories` table it might look like this.

| CategoryID | CategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cars |
| 2 | Bikes |
| 3 | Trucks |

Then the dataset query would look something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM Categories
        UNION 
        SELECT 0, 'Select All'
        ) a 
    ORDER BY 
        CASE CategoryID WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
        CategoryName
```

Here I've used a `CASE` statement to sort alphabetically except where the CategoryID is 0 to make sure it always appears first in the list.

This gives the following output which you can use as your parameter values..

[image]

Then in your main dataset query you can do something like this.

```
SELECT *
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE (catID = @catID OR @catID = 0)
```

@catID is the name of the SSRS parameter and `0` is whatever value you chose for 'Select All'

Comment: For SQL Server consider adding OPTION RECOMPILE to the query containing `WHERE (catID = @catID OR @catID = 0)` so it can prune the WHERE clauses containing the 'SELECT ALL' values before optimizing the query plan.  Otherwise it will reuse the same plan for both a single selected `@cadID`  and `Select All`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation and shift response. I am just wondering how to do the same with the powerbi builder optimized for DAX, Not SQL.

Comment: You need to add the DAX tag to your question to make it clear. You could try using the DAX UNION function, something like. `UNION( YourCurrentTableExpression ,{(0,"Select All")})` . Check out these links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax and https://radacad.com/creating-a-table-in-power-bi-using-dax-table-constructor